# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker Does not support Multi-Stage Build

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I am struggling to get my build deploying to AWS on Docker. I have no idea where the solution lays as this is my first time with Docker. I have got it all working fine locally, but when I deploy I get the following error in Elastic Beanstalk:

```
2020/04/30 05:35:02.330900 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:13.3.0 AS compile-image failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:"docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.
```

This is what my Docker file looks like:

```
FROM node:13-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /opt/ng
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

COPY . ./
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:1.18-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /opt/ng/dist/angular-universal-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Or is this method of Multi-Stage builds not supported by Elastic Beanstalk's Docker version?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Actually I check the following rows in my log file:

```
2020/05/26 17:26:30.327310 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder
2020/05/26 17:26:30.369280 [ERROR] "docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

As you can seen, it tries to make a 'docker pull' with 3 arguments:

1. node:alpine
2. as
3. builder

and of course, that is not possible because it requires only 1 argument. Thus, apparently AWS Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support stage naming. For this reason I solved using an Unnamed builder:

```
FROM node:13-alpine
```

and in the end:

```
COPY --from=0 /opt/ng/dist/angular-universal-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Final Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/ng
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

COPY . ./
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:1.18-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /opt/ng/dist/angular-universal-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
```

For me it works using that solution. If someone has any problem, please share the last-100-lines log

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this error when using a solution stack that uses 'Amazon Linux 2'. These platforms are new and have some ongoing issues.

> Amazon Linux 2 support for AWS Elastic Beanstalk is in beta release and is subject to change.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-beta.html

Please use a solution stack that has 'Amazon Linux' in the name. You should not face the issue there.

Comment: If you want/need to use `Linux 2`, Alfonso's answer below works.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with the added "as builder."  I got it to work with as builder with the following version of AWS Linux: 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.5.
I have version 24.0.7 of Docker.

Comment: Les, please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: how is this not an answer? it originally had a "thanks" in it, but [the answer it seemed to thank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61529153/11107541) is saying to _not_ use "Amazon Linux 2".

Comment: I'm confused; saying what worked for me is not an answer?  <politeness and cordiality not required here, huh?>

Comment: I suggest to provide more context, since it seems you are referencing [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031810/4430246) that suggested that stage naming ("as builder") in the Dockerfile does not work with this specific setup. Your answer should be understandable on its own.

Comment: Gotcha, probably would have been more appropriate as a reply to bottom of the post to which I was referring, rather than an entirely new answer.